# Cmake with a simple main and library

Tags: cmake

i tried a lot of commands and finally give up.
I know I did it in past.
But please tell me why it doesn't work :,(
Its just a main.c with a little library testlib.h

**$cmake ..**

```
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:15 (add_library):
  Cannot find source file:

    PUBLIC

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .mpp .m .M .mm .ixx .cppm .h
  .hh .h++ .hm .hpp .hxx .in .txx .f .F .for .f77 .f90 .f95 .f03 .hip .ispc


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:15 (add_library):
  No SOURCES given to target: lib
```

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(WTF)

add_executable(result main.c)
set_target_properties(result PROPERTIES
    C_STANDARD 11
    C_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
    C_EXTENSIONS OFF
    
)
set (DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
set (DIRLIBS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs")
message("${DIRLIBS}")
message("${DIR}")
add_library(lib PUBLIC testlib.h testlib.c)
target_include_directories(result PUBLIC ${DIR} ${DIRLIBS} )
set_target_properties(result PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
target_link_libraries(result PUBLIC lib )
```

**$cmake --build .**

```
usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltestlib.h
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/result.dir/build.make:97: result] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/result.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

**main.c**

```
#include "testlib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
//#include "libs/lib2.h"
int main(void){
printf("hw");
f1();
```

**testlib.h**

```
   void f1(void);
```

**testlib.c**

```
  #include <stdio.h>
#include "testlib.h"
void f1(void){
printf("f1");}
```

Comment: lol first I thought I didnt take care on something. But then I compared it with a old project and it is really the same xD But ok maybe I miss something. Just tell me :D

Comment: omg it is so terrible. I also have another (bigger) project. I just add testlib.h into my workspace next to the main.c. I also add this path (maybe again) with target_include_directories. And it also says cannot find testlib.h... ah and I also write it to: target_link_libraries

Comment: target_link_libraries(result PUBLIC testlib.h ) : instead of library you're including a header file

Comment: use target_include_directories() to include headers

Comment: ah ok let me change it to a library

Comment: damn didnt work

Comment: are you sure target_include_directories() is there for paths or not?

Comment: omg are they crazy , what is wrong with cmake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(WTF)

add_executable(result main.c)
set_target_properties(result PROPERTIES
    C_STANDARD 11
    C_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
    C_EXTENSIONS OFF
    
)
set (DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
set (DIRLIBS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs")
message("${DIRLIBS}")
message("${DIR}")
add_library(test STATIC testlib.h testlib.c)
target_include_directories(result PUBLIC ${DIR} ${DIRLIBS} )
set_target_properties(result PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
target_link_libraries(result PUBLIC test )
```

problem is with the syntax of add_library() use [STATIC | SHARED | MODULE] instead of PUBLIC.

Comment: this works :) Yeah the error message was confusing to me xD I should have read the Flags in the documentation :)

Comment: (thank you it made me happy today)

Comment: Happy to help :)